# Android: How to send a picture through a service

Tags: android, web-services, json, wcf

I wonder how is it possible to send a picture.
I am using json to send data and store to database.

But how do I handle a picture? 
How do I send it using json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this:

[How to send an image using json to server in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257515/how-to-send-an-image-using-json-to-server-in-iphone)

Have a look here, shows how to use HTTP with Java:

http://www.java-samples.com/java/POST-toHTTPS-url-free-java-sample-program.htm

Comment: this is not what I was looking for,, Iam using json, How should I send pictures to service.. 
should I make the picture as bytes?

Answer (score 0):

Never send bytes, encode it with base64 and compressing does not really help.